# 32-bit binary stack layout on a x64 Linux OS

Tags: linux, x86-64

Stack layout is well documented in many ways. Especially for *x86* systems as there were numerous tutorials on how to exploit stack overflow on old 32-bit systems many years ago.

So far we can know that on a 32-bit system, the user stack starts from *0xc0000000* address (which is the limit between usermode and kernelmode).

This address is not the same if we take an *Elf32* running on a *x86-64* linux system.

I cannot find this address but I can figure out it is *0xffffe000* thanks to gdb:

`(gdb) x $esp
0xffffd4bc: 0xf7e16a83
(gdb) x/w 0xffffdffc
0xffffdffc: 0x00000000
(gdb) x/w 0xffffe000
0xffffe000: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffe000`

We can actually see that the *0xffffe000* address points to an invalid location (or at least the process doesn't have proper permission to access this memory page).

Yet I cannot especially find a relevant source that tells us that **the gnu stack of a x86 program on a x64 linux starts from 0xffffe000**. Am I doing things wrong?

I can find sources telling us about *linux-gate.so.1* but I do not think this is the point here.

Any ideas, reversers?

Comment: This is a coincidence, I have the same problem with you about the valid address of 32-bit binary stack on x64.

Comment: What values can you get then?

Comment: I found something probably relevant here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426476/linux-process-virtual-address-spaces-address-range

Comment: I gets closer here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h?v=3.19#L910

Comment: In [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/), the valid range for stack of a process is calculated from [TASK_SIZE](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h?v=3.18#L840) for 32-bit processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The valid stack access range of a (32 or 64 bit) process can be viewed by looking into its *memory map*. We can observe the memory map of a process with id `pid` by `cat /proc/pid/maps`, an example of a `32-bit process` on my 64-bit box:

```
...
09b58000-09b79000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                    [heap]
...
f7785000-f7787000 rw-p 001c7000 00:23 592106               /usr/lib/libc-2.20.so
...
f77c2000-f77c4000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                    [vvar]
f77c4000-f77c5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                    [vdso]
...
f77e8000-f77e9000 rw-p 00022000 00:23 592099               /usr/lib/ld-2.20.so
fff9b000-fffbc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                    [stack]
```

Then the valid range for `stack` is `[0xfff9b000, 0xfffbc000)`, memory access to an address higher or equal than `0xfffbc000` will trigger `memory access violation` exception. According to [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/), this range is calculated when the kernel [maps the binary into the memory](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c?v=3.18#L571), and by [several](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c?v=3.18#L555) [functions](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/exec.c?v=3.18#L640), the interesting input for them is [`STACK_TOP`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h?v=3.18#L840) which is defined by `TASK_SIZE` for [32-bit processes](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h?v=3.18#L834).

Comment: Well, I guess this deserves several further investigations. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks @GeoffreyR., you are welcome. In fact, I have the same question with you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer.

One can determine wether the memory layout ends up to **0xc0000000** or **0xffffe000** thanks to the [personality system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/personality). By reading the *ADDR_LIMIT_3GB* flag it is possible to figure out wether a 32-bit process is mapped up to **0xc0000000** or **0xffffe000**.

I could not tell why the **0xffffe000** is relevant, except that it is 8192 bytes shorter that the end of a *4GB memory space*. Maybe it has something to do with the kernel stack size.